# How do I deploy documents from one sandbox to another sandbox?

Tags: deployment

I am deploying a customer portal. Right now I am going from a development sandbox to a staging sandbox.

I have CSS, PDF, PNG, and HTML files in a folder in Documents.

In my package.xml I tried:

```
<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Document</name>
</types>
```

That didn't work
Do I need to download all those files to a folder in Documents in the staging sandbox? Or is there a way to migrate the folder from one sandbox to another?

Thank you,
Haya

Answer (score 5):

To retrieve Documents from ANT you need to mention the name of the folder in which the document is saved as well as the name of the folder & document together.
Example:

folder

folder/image.gif

folder/image.png

folder/file.doc

Document

Retrieving Documents: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_document.htm

Regards,
Haya

Comment: To all reading this question this should be the correct way forward especially if you use the image document as an app logo.

Answer (score 4):

I think all CSS, PDF, PNG, and HTML files in Documents are treated as Data/records and so can not be deployed from one sandbox to another sandbox. It is different from your static resources(which is meta data) which can be be deployed from one org to another.

So in short you will need to download your data and then again upload it in target org.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Would you know if there is another way to migrate data/records besides using the deployment tools?

Comment: if you dont want to download and upload them again, you could use the Data Loader to move your documents.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
<types>     
        <members>Image_Public/img1</members>    
        <members>Image_Public/img2</members>        
        <members>Image_Public/img3</members>
        <name>Document</name>
    </types>
```

You can set this in a package.xml and then use for retrieved or deployemnt via vs code and sfdx
[see screenshot below]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hana,
You want to migrate documents from one sandbox to another, correct? If not, sorry! I am answering the wrong question here.

Files in Salesforce Documents are treated as files and not data. Things like Applications store their logos, start pages etc. there. They can be migrated from sandbox to sandbox using metadata API. Force.com IDE/ ANT can help you.

The trick is to realize that they are always part of a folder. They can be called "unfiled$public" but they are in a folder. If you use the Force.com IDE and look for Documents metadata type, you will find them there. Select the ones and their folders. Then, you can "Deploy to Server" to move them to another sandbox Org.

If you need help with this, please let me know and I can walk you through this. You can contact me here: sridhar removethisstring @  dreamfactory.com

Good luck.

Sridhar

Comment: Thank you for your offer, Sridhar, but I resolved the issue and migrated my documents using ANT.
I would like to ask you questions if I run into more issues.
Regards,
Haya